# 2 inline divs, both 50% width collapse?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the two divs sit side by side at 50% width?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2p2Qd/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="big_div">
    <div class="pic_1 pix">
        <img src="pic1" width="50%" height="30%"/>
    </div>
    <div class="pic_2 pix">
        <img src="pic2" width="50%" height="30%"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pix{
    display:inline;
}
```

Please comment, any logic in the right step helps.

Comment: Try applying width:100%; to big_div and also playing with float:left; (Currently mobile and jsfiddle does not play nice)

Comment: @aDroidman thanks for the response! :D I tried applying 100% to `big_div` but it did not help. As for `float`, I don't want to have to float...what if I have 16 divs? It isn't going to help.

Comment: How about using `display: table` technique -  http://jsfiddle.net/2p2Qd/4/

Comment: @davidpauljunior you are a saint, please post the answer so I can award you.

Comment: @13ruce1337 - I don't see what having 16 divs has to do with anything.  You can float more than one item.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch that was a bad example. I don't want them to stick to the left.

Comment: @13ruce1337 - be aware, `display:table` doesn't work on IE7

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch thank you. some of my projects I try to adhere to older technology but this one doesn't need to. +1

Comment: @13ruce1337 Try setting `font-size:0` on your parent element and it works just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/2p2Qd/7/

Comment: @JunM epic, but what if I want some font in `.big_div`(parent)? This is a point in the right direction of the greater question of why this does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use floats then you could use the `display: table` technique.  It'll allow you to keep adding more and they'll fit perfectly across the container.

You'll need to remove the inline percentage width and heights on the images.

```
.big_div {
  display: table;    
}
.pix{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2p2Qd/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `float`, use `display:inline-block` (here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2p2Qd/8/).)

**CSS**

```
.big_div { font-size:0; }

.pix{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
}

.pix img { width:100%; }
```

We have to set the font-size to 0 because otherwise there will be space between the divs ([more information](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).)

Comment: as @JunM pointed out. `.big_div {font-size:0;}` works in itself. refer to comments.

Comment: Also note, that IE8 has some issues with inline-block, there are some hacks to solve it, but just be aware.

Answer (score 0):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2p2Qd/2/)

I've changed a bit on your `html` and use this `css`:

```
.big_div {    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

img {
    width:50%;
    height:30%;
    float: left;
}
```

OR you can use `display: inline-block` and set `font-size:0` on parent element

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2p2Qd/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the width & height on the image tag. Keep them at 100% it'll distort the image if you do.

Make the .pix class width 50% and float left or right. It can't be inline & maintain width. The divs must remain display: block to have layout.

Anyway heres an example http://jsfiddle.net/bamboo/T3p7h/1/

```
.big_div {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #00B7FF;
}

.pix {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```